# Vaadin layout expansion

Tags: java, html, css, vaadin, vaadin7

Using Vaadin 7, I'm trying to accomplish a layout similar to other questions asked here, yet with one major difference:

I want my content layout to fill out the remaining space *only if there is not enough content within*. This will result in a layout such the the following:

[image: without content]

I also want the layout to be able to do the following:

When I add more content, enough to fill the content layout area, and proceed to add more, the footer will stay in place, scrollbar appears and the content added after will be added below the footer.

In addition to the first picture, adding enough content should result in the following layout:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether I understand your question correctly or not but lets try my code and see if it helps:

```
    final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    layout.setMargin(true);
    layout.setSpacing(true);
    layout.setStyleName("flow_visible");
    final HorizontalLayout navBarLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
    final VerticalLayout contentLayout = new VerticalLayout();
    final VerticalLayout spacingLayout = new VerticalLayout();
    final HorizontalLayout footerLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
    String dummyText = "TDummy text";
    navBarLayout.addComponent(new Label("Navigation bar"));
    navBarLayout.setStyleName("navbar");
    navBarLayout.setWidth("100%");

    contentLayout.setSizeFull();
    contentLayout.setSpacing(true);
    Button addButton = new Button("Add more content",
            (Button.ClickListener) clickEvent -> {
                contentLayout.addComponent(new Label(dummyText),
                        contentLayout.getComponentCount() - 2);
            });
    contentLayout.addComponent(addButton);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        contentLayout.addComponent(new Label(dummyText));
    }
    spacingLayout.setSizeFull();
    contentLayout.addComponent(spacingLayout);
    contentLayout.setExpandRatio(spacingLayout, 1f);

    footerLayout.addComponent(new Label("Footer"));
    footerLayout.setStyleName("footer");
    footerLayout.setWidth("100%");
    contentLayout.addComponent(footerLayout);

    layout.addComponent(navBarLayout);
    layout.addComponent(contentLayout);
    layout.setSizeFull();
    layout.setExpandRatio(contentLayout, 1f);
```

How this code works: [http://i.imgur.com/1HH1wm7.gif](https://i.imgur.com/1HH1wm7.gif)

Comment: Hi qtdzz, and thank you for posting a very valid solution to my problem! Unfortunately I already have achieved the layout you present, but what I wanted was the same with a tiny addition: Before the content middle layout is expanded to fill the screen like in your example, I would like for the footer to be at the very bottom, and not immediately below the content area.

Comment: Hi,@Syncretic I edited the code to fit with your requirements. I added a new spacingLayout after the content and moved the footerLayout into contentLayout. I am not sure it's a good solution or not but at least it works for your case.

Comment: Thank you so much, that is exactly what I tried to achieve! I've cleaned up my original post to try and clarify and let others benefit from your solution.

Comment: One final question: Does the css class "flow_visible" from your solution have any significant styling that's necessary to achieve this?

Comment: Ah, Im sorry. I forgot saying it explicitly. "flow_visible" style should be **overflow: visible**